# Stop duplicate rows in dynamic drop down

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, users and lifts.

On my UI (php webpage), I have two drop downs (as well as others, irrelevant), one drop down is [userlastname, userfirstname], and the other is [destination]

the query i am using is this:

```
SELECT * FROM lifts l JOIN users u ON l.user_id=u.uid GROUP BY l.id;
```

which gives me the list of usernames in users (correctly)

```
[Harvey Fletcher]
[Ronald McDonald]
[Harvey Fletcher]
```

and also a list of all destinations

```
[Destination 1]
[Destination 2]
[Destination 3]
```

But as you can see from the usernames list, [Harvey Fletcher] has appeared twice. How can I stop this from happening? Table structure below.

Users:

```
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid                 | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title               | varchar(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| firstname           | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lastname            | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email               | varchar(500) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password            | varchar(500) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| reg_no              | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| vehicle_make        | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| vehicle_colour      | varchar(25)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| licence_no          | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address_line1       | varchar(75)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address_line2       | varchar(75)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| town_city           | varchar(75)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| postcode            | varchar(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| reputation_positive | int(10)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| reputation_negative | int(10)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| telephone_number    | char(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Lifts:

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id         | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lift_to         | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lift_from       | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| quote_price     | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| available_seats | int(2)       | YES  |     | 1       |                |
| depart_date     | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| depart_time     | varchar(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pickup_location | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Info:
Harvey Fletcher is only in users table once
Harvey Fletcher has two 'lifts', which is why it appears twice.
Ronald McDonald only has one, so only appears once, but if I added a second lift, would be displayed 2 times.

Comment: Use two separate calls to DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group your query to users instead of lifts:

```
SELECT * FROM lifts l JOIN users u ON l.user_id=u.uid GROUP BY u.uid;
```

Comment: This only displays the first option for each user in the destination. Example: [Destination 1], [Destination 3]. But I also need [Destination 2] to be present.

Comment: You need two different queries for that

Comment: @HarveyFletcher how it possible that you have all destination but you dont want respective users in single query?

Comment: Thanks. I've used two separate queries and its working.

Comment: @AjayKorat, I needed all the locations, but only want each user to appear once in the list.